# INSERT INTO MySQL table in batches to avoid locks on process while inserting large number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am performing`insert into` operation in MYSQL table to insert a large number of rows from one table into another, but it locks the process. It is a very complex query for me to filter rows from two tables for `insert into` operation and works absolutely fine on small test-tables. But when I fire this query on the actual table it hangs the process and I need to `KILL` the process. Can anyone provide me the information about chunk operation or batch process to insert data my table? I do not know how can I improve my solution. Can anyone add any inputs? Thanks in advance.

Here is my query to insert rows in the `table1` by performing some join and alias operations on `table2` and `table3`:

```
INSERT INTO table1 
        (utc,date,area_in,area_out,value) 
        select t0.utc, STR_TO_DATE(t0.utc, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%iZ")as date, d.country_code AS area_in , c.country_code AS area_out , (t1.value -t0.value) AS value                           
        from table2 t0
        INNER JOIN table3 c ON t0.area_out = c.country_code
        INNER JOIN table3 d ON t0.area_in = d.country_code
        join table2 t1
          on  t1.Utc  = t0.Utc
          and t1.area_in  = t0.area_out
          and t1.area_out = t0.area_in
          where (t0.value = 0 or t0.value <> 0)
          and (t1.area_in > t0.area_in)
          and 
          NOT EXISTS 
          (
          SELECT 1 
          FROM table1 t2 WHERE 
          t2.utc = t0.utc AND 
          t2.area_in = t0.area_in AND
          t2.area_out = t0.area_out 
           ) ;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server? Please remove tags that don't apply to your question.

Comment: What DBMS are you *actually* using?  This does not look like `SQL Server` syntax.

Comment: I am using Mysql db.

Comment: Did you try running this as a scheduled job during off hours?

Comment: @ Isaiah3015  I didn't get your point.

Comment: If most of the time is taken by the `SELECT` statement, you could reduce the time that `table1` is locked by populating a temporary table with the results of the `SELECT` statement and then inserting from the temp table into `table1`.